# How would one produce 8/16 bit music on Linux?

Tags: sound, music

So, I've been interested in making 16 bit (retro videogame style) music on Ubuntu for a while now but every time I look it up on Google, it's always showing me how to drop my regular every day music down to 16bits.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a tracker, to organize, create, and modify sounds. [Here are some sources](http://woolyss.com/chipmusic-chiptrackers.php)

I like milkytracker, which takes a little getting used to. its interface isn't what I would call intuitive, but it has some neat features, like being able to draw the sound you want to make. 
There are numerous online tutorials as well.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maip6QAAVRQ

Answer (score 0):

The old 8-Bit stuff is characterized by subtractive synthesis based on the waveform "square", with addition of envelopes and filters.

You can try using Amsynth to create the typical 8-Bit sound  [Wiki - Linux Audio Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_audio_software#Synthesizers)

An example of how to program such sounds (different software, same principle) can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FC8c8iEMuMY)

Answer (score -1):

Try installing Audacity.  It allows you to make projects with custom sample rates.  See http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features for the features.  I believe a sudo apt-get install audacity will work.

Comment: I talking about old 8/16 bit techno music http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5CBC46U32c